# Having trouble developing incrementMinutesBy method

Tags: java

I am trying to create a digital clock an am currently trying to fix my `incrementMinutesBy` method.

I need this method to increase both the minutes and if necessary the hours. I need the final `this.minutes` to be the sum of the previous `this.minutes` and the parameter, modulo the number of minutes in an hour.

I also need the final `this.hours` to be the sum of the previous `this.minutes` and the parameter, divided by the number of minutes in an hour. My method so far begins on line 94.

```java
public class DigitalClock
{
    private int currentHour;
    private int currentMinutes;

    public int getHour()
    {
        return currentHour;
    }

    public void setHour(int currentHour)
    {
        this.currentHour = currentHour;
    }

    public int getMinutes()
    {
        return currentMinutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int currentMinutes)
    {
        this.currentMinutes = currentMinutes;
    }

    public static final int HOUR_MAX = 23; // Refactored hourly max
    public static final int HOUR_MIN = 0; // Refactored hourly min
    public static final int MINUTES_MAX = 59; // Refactored minute max
    public static final int MINUTES_MIN = 0; // Refactored minute min
    public static final int TOTAL_NUMBERS_HOURS = 24;
    public static final int TOTAL_NUMBERS_MINUTES = 60;

    /**
     * Creates a new digital clock with the time set at the given
     * hours and minutes.
     * 
     * @precondition 0 <= hour <= 23 AND 0 <= minutes <= 59
     * @postcondition getHour()==hour AND getMinutes()==minutes
     * 
     * @param hour the hour to set for the time
     * @param minutes the minutes to set for the time
     */
    public DigitalClock (int hour, int minutes) // 2-parameter constructor (parameters: int hour and int minutes)
    {
        // enforcing hourly preconditions using appropriate ranges
        if (hour >= HOUR_MIN && hour <= HOUR_MAX){
            currentHour = hour;
        }
        else {
            currentHour = 0;
            //throw an exception on invalid hour's input
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input for Hours");
        }
        // enforcing minute preconditions using appropriate ranges
        if (minutes >= MINUTES_MIN && minutes <= MINUTES_MAX) {
            currentMinutes = minutes;
        }
        else {
            currentMinutes = 0;
            //throw an exception on invalid minute's input
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input for Minutes");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Advances the entire clock by the given number of hours.
     * If the hours advances past 23 they wrap around.
     * 
     * @precondition hours >= 0
     * @postcondition  the clock has moved forward
     *  by the appropriate number of hours
     * 
     * @param hours the number of hours to add
     */
    public void incrementHoursBy(int hour)
    {
        int h = getHour()+hour; {
        // if statement enforcing precondition
        if(h>HOUR_MAX)
            h%=TOTAL_NUMBERS_HOURS;
        // increasing this.hours by the parameter 
        setHour(h);}
        // if statement which prevents negative hours from being inputted
        if (h<HOUR_MIN) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input. No negative hours");
        }
    }
    
    public void incrementMinutesBy(int minutes) {
        int m = getMinutes()+minutes;
        m++;
        if (m > MINUTES_MAX) {
            m%=TOTAL_NUMBERS_MINUTES;
            setMinutes(m);
        }
        if (m<MINUTES_MIN) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input. No negative minutes");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Minutes are: "+m);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DigitalClock obj=new DigitalClock(12, 15);
        obj.incrementHoursBy(HOUR_MAX);
        obj.incrementMinutesBy(MINUTES_MAX);
        DigitalClockFormatter();
    }

    public static void DigitalClockFormatter() {
        // method for class DigitalClockFormatter

    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use class [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html)?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest I am new to coding and so I am kind of just putting it together in a way I understand

Comment: Maybe try Oracle's [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the implementation, it's beter to save `totalMinutes` internaly, but not the separate `hours` and `minutes`.

```java
public final class DigitalClock {

    private static final int MINUTES_PER_HOUR = (int)TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(1);
    private static final int MINUTES_PER_DAY = (int)TimeUnit.DAYS.toMinutes(1);

    private int totalMinutes;

    public DigitalClock(int hour, int minutes) {
        setHour(hour);
        setMinutes(minutes);
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return totalMinutes / MINUTES_PER_HOUR;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return totalMinutes % MINUTES_PER_HOUR;
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) {
        if (hour < 0 || hour > 23)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'hour' should be within [0;23]");

        totalMinutes = (int)TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hour) + getMinutes();
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        if (minutes < 0 || minutes > 59)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'minutes' should be within [0;59]");

        totalMinutes = (int)TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(getHour()) + minutes;
    }

    public void incrementHoursBy(int hour) {
        totalMinutes = withinDay((int)TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hour) + totalMinutes);
    }

    public void incrementMinutesBy(int minutes) {
        totalMinutes = withinDay(totalMinutes + minutes);
    }

    private static int withinDay(int totalMinutes) {
        totalMinutes %= MINUTES_PER_DAY;

        if (totalMinutes < 0)
            totalMinutes = MINUTES_PER_DAY + totalMinutes;

        return totalMinutes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinutes());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your calculations can also be achieved by subtraction. Consider the following example.

If `currentHour` is 23 and you add two hours, then the result should be 1 (one).

```
23 + 2 = 25
25 % 24 = 1
25 - 24 = 1
```

Similarly for `currentMinutes`. However, for `currentMinutes` you also need to increment `currentHour` if the result of the increment (to `currentMinutes`) is greater than `MINUTES_MAX`. And when you increment `currentHour` you also need to check whether the incremented `currentHour` value is greater than `HOUR_MAX`. In other words, if `currentHour` is 23 and `currentMinutes` is 55 and you `incrementMinutesBy(10)`, then:

```
55 + 10 = 65
65 - 60 = 5
```

Therefore `currentMinutes` is set to 5 and `currentHour` needs to be incremented. Therefore:

```
23 + 1 = 24
24 - 24 = 0
```

So `currentHour` needs to be set to 0 (zero).

Also, as explained in the book [Java by Comparison](https://java.by-comparison.com/), methods need to *fail fast* so the first thing you should do in both method `incrementHoursBy` and method `incrementMInutesBy` is to check the value of the method argument – and not the result of the calculation. After all, you wrote in the code comments that the pre-condition is that the method argument not be negative – even though I think it would be logical to be able to set the digital clock backwards. I mean that's what you do when daylight saving ends and the clocks get turned back one hour. But then again, with your [digital] clock, you could achieve the same result by invoking `incrementHoursBy(HOUR_MAX)`

Consider the following code:

```java
public class DigitalClock {
    private int currentHour;
    private int currentMinutes;

    public int getHour() {
        return currentHour;
    }

    public void setHour(int currentHour) {
        this.currentHour = currentHour;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return currentMinutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int currentMinutes) {
        this.currentMinutes = currentMinutes;
    }

    public static final int HOUR_MAX = 23; // Refactored hourly max
    public static final int HOUR_MIN = 0; // Refactored hourly min
    public static final int MINUTES_MAX = 59; // Refactored minute max
    public static final int MINUTES_MIN = 0; // Refactored minute min
    public static final int TOTAL_NUMBERS_HOURS = 24;
    public static final int TOTAL_NUMBERS_MINUTES = 60;

    /**
     * Creates a new digital clock with the time set at the given hours and minutes.
     * 
     * @precondition 0 <= hour <= 23 AND 0 <= minutes <= 59
     * @postcondition getHour()==hour AND getMinutes()==minutes
     * 
     * @param hour    the hour to set for the time
     * @param minutes the minutes to set for the time
     */
    public DigitalClock(int hour, int minutes) {
        // enforcing hourly preconditions using appropriate ranges
        if (hour >= HOUR_MIN && hour <= HOUR_MAX) {
            currentHour = hour;
        }
        else {
            currentHour = 0;
            // throw an exception on invalid hour's input
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input for Hours");
        }
        // enforcing minute preconditions using appropriate ranges
        if (minutes >= MINUTES_MIN && minutes <= MINUTES_MAX) {
            currentMinutes = minutes;
        }
        else {
            currentMinutes = 0;
            // throw an exception on invalid minute's input
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input for Minutes");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Advances the entire clock by the given number of hours. If the hours advances
     * past 23 they wrap around.
     * 
     * @precondition hours >= 0
     * @postcondition the clock has moved forward by the appropriate number of hours
     * 
     * @param hours the number of hours to add
     */
    public void incrementHoursBy(int hour) {
        // if statement which prevents negative hours from being inputted
        if (hour < HOUR_MIN  ||  hour > HOUR_MAX) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input. Between 0 & 23");
        }
        int h = currentHour + hour;
        // if statement enforcing precondition
        if (h > HOUR_MAX) {
            h -= TOTAL_NUMBERS_HOURS;
        }
        // increasing this.hours by the parameter
        setHour(h);
    }

    public void incrementMinutesBy(int minutes) {
        if (minutes < MINUTES_MIN  ||  minutes > MINUTES_MAX) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input. Between 0 & 59");
        }
        int m = getMinutes() + minutes;
        if (m > MINUTES_MAX) {
            incrementHoursBy(1);
            m -= TOTAL_NUMBERS_MINUTES;
            setMinutes(m);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DigitalClock obj = new DigitalClock(22, 55);
        obj.incrementHoursBy(1);
        obj.incrementMinutesBy(10);
        DigitalClockFormatter(obj);
    }

    public static void DigitalClockFormatter(DigitalClock dc) {
        System.out.printf("%02d:%02d", dc.getHour(), dc.getMinutes());
    }
}
```

Running above code displays:

```
00:05
```

Alternatively, you could use the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

```java
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class DigiClok {
    private LocalTime clock;

    public DigiClok(int hour, int minute) {
        clock = LocalTime.of(hour, minute); // throws java.time.DateTimeException if invalid arguments
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return clock.getHour();
    }

    public void setHour(int currentHour) {
        // class 'java.time.LocalTime' is immutable.
        int minute = clock.getMinute();
        clock = LocalTime.of(currentHour, minute);
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return clock.getMinute();
    }

    public void setMinutes(int currentMinutes) {
        int hour = clock.getHour();
        clock = LocalTime.of(hour, currentMinutes);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        boolean equal = this == obj;
        if (!equal) {
            if (obj instanceof DigiClok) {
                DigiClok other = (DigiClok) obj;
                equal = clock.equals(other.clock);
            }
        }
        return equal;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return clock.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return clock.toString();
    }

    public void incrementHoursBy(int hour) {
        clock = clock.plusHours(hour); // also handles negative 'hour'
    }

    public void incrementMinutesBy(int minutes) {
        clock = clock.plusMinutes(minutes); // also handles negative 'minute'
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DigiClok obj = new DigiClok(22, 55);
        obj.incrementHoursBy(1);
        obj.incrementMinutesBy(10);
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```